# External links are not getting crawled

Tags: nutch

I'm working on a custom parse plugin for nutch and ran into an issue. I want to crawl all URLs in a specific area of seed url. But nutch ignores external links and these links are not getting crawled.

eg : seed url - `https://in.news.yahoo.com`
It contains links to sites like timesofindia.com,thehindu.com etc but these links are not getting crawled.

My nutch-site.xml contains :-

```
<property>
  <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

And regex-url filter accepts anything else.(with regex +.).
I wonder why nutch is ignoring certain external links in the url given as seed. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,  I found a workaround for this :

- Add some additional code snippets to your parsefilter.
- Select the links that you wish to crawl using Jsoup selector elements.
  For Example, I am selecting links in a particular div
- Set this newOutLinks to your parse result and Nutch will accept this links and starts crawling.

Code sample for step 2:

```
List<Outlink> outLinks=new ArrayList<Outlink>(); 
Outlink outLink;
String link; 
Elements elements = document.select("div.show a[href]"); 
for (Element element : elements) {
link=element.absUrl("href"); 
outLink=new Outlink(absoluteUrl,element.text()); 
outLinks.add(outLink); 
}
Outlink[] newOutLinks = (Outlink[])outLinks.toArray(new Outlink[outLinks.size()]);
```

Comment: Thanks.It was helpful :)